# Stacked100ColumnSeries set ToolTip to percentage value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts, tooltip

I'm currently working on a program that has to display many different kinds of charts, one of them being a Stacked100 chart. I'm using the System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.Stacked100ColumnSeries. 
The default tooltip the columns show ist their value. However I want the percantage value to be displayed instead.
I made a style for the DataPoints which looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="SolidColorStacked100DataPointStyle" TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:DataPoint}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SolidColorDataPointStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:DataPoint}">
                <Border x:Name="Root"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Border.ToolTip>
                        <ContentControl Content=""/> <!-- This is where I set the ToolTip Content -->
                    </Border.ToolTip>
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <!--Change Border appearance-->
                        <Border BorderBrush="#CCFFFFFF"
                                    BorderThickness="1">
                            <Border BorderBrush="#77FFFFFF"
                                    BorderThickness="1">
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="TextBlockValue" Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}" TextAlignment="Center">
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But I don't find any way to access the DataPoint's percentage value from here to bind them.
I found out that in the WinForms Charts there are keywords like `#Percantage` that can be used for that. Is there something similar in WPF?
Has anyone got an idea how to solve this Problem, or may there even be an easier way?